Многопоточный сервер python 3
сделал сервер на python3 с помощью HTTPServer. Когда подключается более одного человека все ломается. Работает все в один поток. Код вот:
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()

Есть ли способ сделать этот сервер многопоточным?

Без значительных переделок - нельзя. Возьмите готовый gunicorn.

Здравствуйте, работают ли там cgi скрипты?

Нет, только WSGI. Для CGI используйте например Apache. В любом случае, http.server из стандартной библиотеки Python для какого-то реального применения не предназначен, про это в том числе в документации написано.

Все простые встроенные питоновские веб-сервисы однопоточные, включая популярный Flask.

from http.server import ThreadingHTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = ThreadingHTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()

ThreadingHTTPServer - Этот класс идентичен HTTPServer, но для обработки запросов использует потоки с использованием метода ThreadingMixIn. Это полезно для обработки веб-браузерами предварительного открытия сокетов, которые HTTPServer будут ждать бесконечно.
